# Python move parts of rows to previous row based on matching rows from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames `df1`:

```
    Name Month  Amount  Status
0   Bill   Apr       0           
1   Bill   May       0           
2   Bill   Jun     100  member
3  Sally   Apr       0           
4  Sally   May       0           
5  Sally   Jun     200  member
6    Tom   Apr       0           
7    Tom   May     300  member
8    Tom   Jun       0
```

and `df2`:

```
   Name Month
0  Bill   Jun
1   Tom   May
```

I am looking to update `df1` whenever there is a match in `df2` on Name and Month and move the Amount and Status to the previous Month. It can be assumed there is always a previous Month to move to for each person and that the rows are already in the correct order by Name and Month. The intended result would be as follows:

```
    Name Month  Amount  Status
0   Bill   Apr       0           
1   Bill   May     100  member           
2   Bill   Jun       0
3  Sally   Apr       0           
4  Sally   May       0           
5  Sally   Jun     200  member
6    Tom   Apr     300  member          
7    Tom   May       0
8    Tom   Jun       0
```

I believe there is a way to do this with `itterows()` but is there a more direct approach to use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
# merge to find rows with Name, Month in df2
exist = df1[['Name','Month']].merge(df2.assign(exist=1), how='left')['exist'].notna()

# find the previous rows
prev_rows = exist.groupby(df1['Name']).shift(-1, fill_value=False)

# fill the previous rows
df1.loc[prev_rows, ['Amount','Status']] = df1.loc[exist, ['Amount','Status']].to_numpy()

# remove the given rows
df1.loc[exist, ['Amount','Status']] = [0, None]
```

Output:

```
    Name Month  Amount  Status
0   Bill   Apr       0    None
1   Bill   May     100  member
2   Bill   Jun       0    None
3  Sally   Apr       0    None
4  Sally   May       0    None
5  Sally   Jun     200  member
6    Tom   Apr     300  member
7    Tom   May       0    None
8    Tom   Jun       0    None
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the data look sorted by month per each user, I will assume that it's not predefined. So we have to make some mapping of previous months in order to know where to move data. On the next step we set `('Name','Month')` as the data index, and create an index subset of the origin and destination where to move values. Finally we just locate data in the origin and move them to the destination:

```
from calendar import month_abbr

month = month_abbr[1:]    # skip '' at the beginning
month_mapping = {m: month[i-1] for i, m in enumerate(month)}

# create the origin and destination index of data to move
destin = df2.assign(Month=df2['Month'].map(month_mapping))
destin = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(destin)
origin = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2)

# use (Name, Month) as index to locate data to move
data = df1.set_index(['Name','Month'])
data.loc[destin] = data.loc[origin].values   # use np.array to avoid merging on index
data.loc[origin] = (0, float('nan')) 
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. You brought up a good point that I did not think to include in my original question - it can be assumed that the data will already be in order by name and date. I have updated the question to include this important information - thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# Your data
data1 = {
    'Name': ['Bill', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Sally', 'Sally', 'Sally', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom'],
    'Month': ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'],
    'Amount': [0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 200, 0, 300, 0],
    'Status': ['', '', 'member', '', '', 'member', '', 'member', '']
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {
    'Name': ['Bill', 'Tom'],
    'Month': ['Jun', 'May']
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Step 1: Create a column 'match' in df1 indicating if the row matches with df2
df1['match'] = df1[['Name', 'Month']].apply(tuple, 1).isin(df2[['Name', 'Month']].apply(tuple, 1))

# Step 2: Shift the 'Amount' and 'Status' columns up within each group if the 'match' column is True
df1['Amount'] = df1.groupby('Name').apply(lambda group: group['Amount'].shift(1) if group['match'].any() else group['Amount']).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df1['Status'] = df1.groupby('Name').apply(lambda group: group['Status'].shift(1) if group['match'].any() else group['Status']).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

# Step 3: Clean up and format the final dataframe
df1 = df1.drop('match', axis=1)
df1['Amount'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df1['Status'].fillna('', inplace=True)

print(df1)
```

the out put :

```
    Name Month  Amount  Status
0   Bill   Apr       0       
1   Bill   May     100  member
2   Bill   Jun       0       
3  Sally   Apr       0       
4  Sally   May       0       
5  Sally   Jun     200  member
6    Tom   Apr     300  member
7    Tom   May       0       
8    Tom   Jun       0
```

Here's my approach to achieve the desired outcome:
Create a column in df1 indicating if the row matches with df2.
Based on the match column, shift the Amount and Status columns up within each group.
Clean up and format the final dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I ran the code and it does not produce the intended output.

Comment: I like reading other people's code as an alternative to my own view of the problem. I like it even more if the code is commented. Could you add a description of the logic of your code, please?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thank you to motivated of me @Vitalizzare now is it good ?

Comment: @Jack There's a problem in your code on step 2: `.shift(1)` moves data down, not up as it would be with `.shift(-1)`. I think that's why @Maxxmilo noted that the code _does not produce the intended output_